# Adding column header to series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to get my series in to a dataframe and rename the headers to Month and Minutes.

Below I'm grouping the data in to 'df'

```
df = data
df = df.groupby(df['endTime'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m'))['Minutes'].sum().sort_index()
print(df)
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Then I'm transforming the series in to a dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(df1)
```

At this point the column header starts being on a different level as if they're on separate rows
[image]

I can't work out how to then correct this or change the column names in any other way.
I'm using Jupyter Notebook

```
             Minutes
endTime             
2019-10   516.386967
2019-11  4423.741683
2019-12  5508.101017
2020-01  3802.073583
2020-02  3790.562850
2020-03  3260.039417
2020-04  1913.841267
2020-05  1554.578183
2020-06  2094.596467
2020-07  3061.289633
2020-08  1676.243450
2020-09  4790.751267
2020-10  6404.273800
```

Comment: welcome to SO! Can you paste the data as text? Makes it difficult to copy if you use images

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan when I paste the data in, it loses all formatting and I can't see a way of attaching the on a spreadsheet. any advise?

Comment: format as code... the `{}` button on the editor

Comment: thanks for that. I've added the data in.

Comment: try `df.groupby(df['endTime'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m'))['Minutes'].sum().reset_index()`

Comment: Ahhh thank you so much! That was driving me mad! It's not giving me the tick to accept your comment as the answer but if you resubmit as an answer, I'll tick that one :)

Comment: done! thanks so much!

Comment: Btw, groupby already sorts the data so you dont have to do sort index.

Comment: Thanks for that Joe Ferndz! I didn't realise that. Originally I had the month as text so it was showing in a alphabetical order which is why I went looking to sort by the index instead. Good to know I can remove it though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try -

```
df.groupby(df['endTime'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m'))['Minutes'].sum().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `endTime` column is the index of the DataFrame after running `groupby`. This explains why it is displayed separately. If you want to get the `endTime` back as regular column in the DataFrame, you can just run the following command:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is

```
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
```